# Select database with laravel 5.5

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to query the database and get user information.
I use the adminlte System but when I run the view it returns a variable error.

HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $users = DB::select('select * from users');

        return view('vendor.adminlte.page', ['users' => $users]);
    }

}
```

Page.blade.php

```
@extends('adminlte::master')

@section('adminlte_css')
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/dist/css/skins/skin-' . config('adminlte.skin', 'blue') . '.min.css')}} ">
    @stack('css')
    @yield('css')
@stop

@section('body_class', 'skin-' . config('adminlte.skin', 'blue') . ' sidebar-mini ' . (config('adminlte.layout') ? [
    'boxed' => 'layout-boxed',
    'fixed' => 'fixed',
    'top-nav' => 'layout-top-nav'
][config('adminlte.layout')] : '') . (config('adminlte.collapse_sidebar') ? ' sidebar-collapse ' : ''))

@section('body')
    <div class="wrapper">

<div class="wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="/home" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>U</b></span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>UNIDAS</b></span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-success">4</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">Você tem 4 mensagens</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- start message -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Informática
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 minutos</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Está conseguindo concluir?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end message -->
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Financeiro
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 horas</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Está conseguindo concluir?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Contabilidade
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Hoje</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Está conseguindo concluir?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Institucional
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Ontem</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Está conseguindo concluir?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Gerência
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 Dias</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Está conseguindo concluir?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">Ler todas Mensagens</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">Você tem 10 notificações</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>Não Imprimir Colorido
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-warning text-yellow"></i>Nova Reunião Redir
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-red"></i>Aviso Copa
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart text-green"></i>Data Congresso Internacional
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-user text-red"></i> Banco de Horas
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">Ver todas Notificações</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">Você tem 9 tarefas</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Desenvolver Intranet
                        <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Desenvolver novo layout
                        <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">40% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Desenvolver novo Administrador
                        <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red" style="width: 60%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Unificar superitêndencias
                        <small class="pull-right">80%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow" style="width: 80%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer">
                <a href="#">Ver todas Tarefas</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Richard Nicson</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <p>
                  Richard Nicson Costa de Lima - Desenvolvedor Web
                  <small>Membro desde Agosto. 2018</small>
                </p>
              </li>

              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="/meus-dados" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Perfil</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Sair
                                </a>
                                <form id="logout-form" action="http://intranet.unidas.org.br/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="jmubQRfJenzcLKmbpvyjeMCVeafWedS5IPC36tmk">
                                </form>
                </div>

                              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  @if(config('adminlte.layout') != 'top-nav')
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="images/usuarios/richardnicson.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Richard Nicson</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
        @each('adminlte::partials.menu-item', $adminlte->menu(), 'item')
       </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
@endif
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 1265px;">
    @if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav')

            <div class="container">
            @endif

            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                @yield('content_header')
            </section>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">

                @yield('content')

            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
            @if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav')
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
            @endif
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
@stop

@section('adminlte_js')
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('js')
    @yield('js')
@stop
```

Error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: adminlte (View:
>   /home/unidas/intranet/resources/views/vendor/adminlte/page.blade.php)

Comment: show /home/unidas/intranet/resources/views/vendor/adminlte/page.blade.php

Comment: **adminlte** variable couldn't found in view page. please check it out.

Comment: Please provide the code of your view file. The error is thrown by the view file not the controller.

Comment: You must be writing $adminlte  in page.blade.php which is not defined.

Comment: Posted view page.blade.php.

Comment: your error is coming from the line @each('adminlte::partials.menu-item', $adminlte->menu(), 'item') ... meaning $adminlte is not defined like @Sabbir mentioned

Comment: Very Good,Thanks..